# How to sum value_counts of oposite pairs in two coumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
foo bar value_count
a   b   7
b   a   22
c   d   15
d   c   111
```

I would like to sum up the value counts of opposite pairs. I expect the following output:

```
foo bar value_count
a   b   29
c   d   126
```

I tried to use set() on list of lists before converting the list to a DataFrame above. Apart from the fact that it didn't work, it doesn't solve the problem of summing up the value counts. I suppose the solution must be beyond my programming experience. All other answers that I found here didn't really seem to address my problem.

Comment: One solution among many: `df[['foo', 'bar']] = np.sort(df[['foo', 'bar']]) ; df.groupby(['foo', 'bar'], as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Btw, if you want to use `set` that doesn't allow a groupby as sets are mutable, but this works with `frozenset` ;)